# Selected option from spinner not being displayed in TextView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I want my selected spinner option to be displayed in a TextView in the same activity. 
The multiple options do drop upon clicking the spinner but upon selecting nothing happens; TextView remains unchanged.

Code:

```
package com.kk.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Addproject extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

int mPos;
String mSelection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproject);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.difficultyspinner); ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.difficultyarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_addproject, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Addproject.this.mPos = pos;
    Addproject.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    TextView spinnerresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnertxt);
    spinnerresult.setText(Addproject.this.mSelection);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertxt);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //NOTHING  

}



}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34410884/1318946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

in your `onCreate()` after this line:

```
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In `onCreate()`, you have made your spinner, but not given it a listener.

This means that

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertxt);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Shouldn't be needed in `onItemSelected()`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been on this for more than half a day and could not figure it out.