# Spinner not showing selected item

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

My problem is that after changing data in my `SpinnerArrayAdapter` my `Spinner` does not react to item clicks on `dropDownList`.
However after orientation change occurs everything is working fine(?!).
EDIT: I noticed it does catch the item clicks but not representing/showing it on `Spinner`. Because after orientation change the selected item appears on `Spinner`

**CONSTRUCTION**

I have `AutoCompleteTextView(ACTV)` that's connected to `AutoCompleteAdapter implementing Filterable`. After entering some data into `ACTV` the result is passed to `SpinnerArrayAdapter` that is connected to `Spinner`.

There is a `customListener` set on `AutoCompleteAdapter` that is connected to `SpinnerArrayAdapter` and responsible for passing data between them.

Reason behind such construction is that user can have a 2-step choice. One on drop-down when choosing the data from `ACTV` and second one in case he change his mind.
So you can put POSTCODE in the `ACTV` select province that's connected to and change province when you miss-clicked/changed mind without forcing to enter POSTCODE again.

**CODE**

This is the part that is responsible for data change inside `SpinnerArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
public void setCitiesFromPostcode(ArrayList<String> cities) {
    this.clear();
    this.addAll(cities);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: r u implementing `onItemClick` for that `Spinner`.

Comment: No there is no `onItemClick` on my `Spinner`.

Comment: after change the value in *Adapter* call `onItemSelected` for that `Spinner`

Comment: I don't understand can you elaborate?

Comment: can u show how u set `onItemSelectListener` for that `Spinner`

Comment: There is none. I have not implemented one yet. For now there is only generic one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65200/discussion-between-kaushik-and-jakubw).

Comment: Implement onItemSelectListener in order to get item click work on your drop down list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34410884/1318946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `ArrayAdapter`. I just changed it to `BaseAdapter` and it works. Don't really know what the reason is, but it's somewhere in the implementation of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 2):

Two common causes for this:

1. Event though it may look big enough, if your Spinner is too small it may not be able to display the value, confirm this by hardcoding the Spinner width and height to something large. Using a custom spinner item layout may help if this is the problem.
2. You're using custom objects in your array, not simple Strings or numbers that can be converted to strings. Use a custom `class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter { }` class in this case.

Comment: Thank you! For me it was the first case.