# Spinner Widget won't show the selected text

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

I am creating an android app that uses Cloud Firestore. There is a document in the database containing names that I need to show on the android app. The problem is that while the Spinner widget I am using is populating correctly, the widget does not show the selected text

I have already tried changing the background and text color of the spinner to no avail([Spinner does not show selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354380/spinner-does-not-show-selected-value/34411427#34411427))

Spinner XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="416dp"
        android:onClick="loginButton"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="304dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    List<String> names;
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("Investors").document("InvestorNames").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Map<String, Object> map = documentSnapshot.getData();
                for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()){
                    names.add((String)entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

The Actual Output:
Once value is selected from spinner, it shows nothing, no text appears

The Expected Behaviour:
Once value from spinner is selected, the spinner should show the selected text

Comment: first, check 'names.size()' what about size of ArrayList

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar There are 10 strings in there... I think the spinner is being populated correctly, that is to say when I tap the spinner, the drop down list has all the items it's supposed to have...

Comment: can you post all XML file so we can check

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            // Spinner Drop down elements
           **Populate your List Here** 
     List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
categories.add('');
            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

      @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     view.setSelection(int)
            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

Comment: I actually don't need to show a Toast, I need to show the option the user selected, right there on the spinner itself

Comment: In onItemSelected you will get the index .Use the following: spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_CATEGORY2)

Comment: Also.. Are you suggesting I move the entire list population logic after the setOnItemSelectedListener call?

Comment: No, Please check OnItemSelected. I have made changes there

Comment: the view object doesn't have a setSelection method though

Answer (score 0):

```
     ArrayList<String> routes = new ArrayList<String>();
        // routes filled with values at runtime
        ...
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GOFdroid.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routes);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner destSpinner = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_event_destination);

        String dest = events.get(pos).getDestination();
        int routesPos = routes.indexOf(dest);
        Log.d(TAG, "Dest: " + dest + ", pos: " + routesPos);


        destSpinner.setAdapter(aa);

destSpinner.setSelection(routesPos);
```

Comment: I couldn't find GOFdroid, dialogView

Comment: Danny, That is class name. Like you have MainActivity

Comment: Those don't seem to be predefined classes. What do those classses do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `width` and `height` of the spinner to `wrap_content` like this...

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```